# How can I make iBooks on iPad to store all books locally instead of on iCloud?

Tags: ipad, icloud, books

I have an iPad with IOS 17, and I want to stop paying for iCloud. The problem is that before I started my iCloud subscription I had some books imported in the Books app, and after I started it the iPad automatically uploaded them to iCloud. Now, whenever I turn off "Books" in the list of apps that use iCloud, my books disappear, and they only reappear when I turn it on again.

How can I force Books to store the books only locally, so that I can stop my iCloud subscription?